# How to create a list with specific size of elements

Tags: java, performance, arraylist, collections

Say, I want to create a list quickly which contains 1000 elements. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: *"How to do that ?"* Ask complete strangers to do it for you?  Oh wait, you already have that covered.  [What Have You Tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @AndrewThompson thumbs up for the link

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use [`Collections.nCopies`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#nCopies%28int,%20T%29).

Note however that the list returned is immutable. In fact, the docs says "*it the newly allocated data object is tiny (it contains a single reference to the data object)*".

If you need a mutable list, you would do something like

```
List<String> hellos = new ArrayList<String>(Collections.nCopies(1000, "Hello"));
```

If you want 1000 distinct objects, you can use

```
List<YourObject> objects = Stream.generate(YourObject::new)
                                 .limit(1000)
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Again, there is not guarantees about the capabilities of the resulting list implementation. If you need, say an `ArrayList`, you would do

```
                                 ...
                                 .collect(ArrayList::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

Fastest : `int[] myList = new int[1000]` will contain 1000 elements equal to zero. But I'm sure it doesn't suit your needs. Tell us more of what you need and I might be able to help :)

Comment: I suspect `Collections.nCopies` is faster :-) especially if you have, say, 1000000 elements :-)