# How to create a list of random uuid with specific size of elements in groovy

Tags: performance, groovy, collections

Say, I want to create a list quickly which contains 1000 random UUIDs. What is the best way to accomplish this?

I went through equivalent piece of code in Java:
[How to create a list with specific size of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267348/how-to-create-a-list-with-specific-size-of-elements)

Tried code

```
List<String> generateValidations(final int count) {
        return Stream.generate(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .limit(count)
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
    }
```

But got an eror:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Stream for class: com.test.rds.specifications.ExecuteValidationsSpecification
```

Comment: Missing import `java.util.stream.Stream`; `generate` takes a function.  E.g. `java.util.stream.Stream.generate({UUID.randomUUID().toString()}).limit(count).collect()`

Comment: `java.util.stream.*` is not auto-imported in Groovy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or, without a stream...

```
def listOfUuids = (1..1000).collect { UUID.randomUUID().toString() }
```

Answer (score 2):

this works:

`Stream.generate(UUID::randomUUID).limit(count).collect(Collectors.toList())`